# A biblioteca <openssl/bn.h> faz parte do padrão ANSI C?

Tags: c

Estava procurando como trabalhar como números grandes em e encontrei um blog que fala que era possível trabalhar utilizando a biblioteca ,  queria saber se ela faz parte do padrão ANSI C ?

Comment: Não. Ela está instalada em algum lugar reconhecido pelo compilador como padrão, mas não pertence ao padrão da linguagem.

Comment: Vixe, queria trabalhar com números grandes e essa biblioteca tinha resolvido mas, não vou poder utilizar ela, teria outra biblioteca que seja padrão para trabalhar com números grandes ou um código que faça esse trabalho

Comment: biblioteca padrão para trabalhar com grandes números? Não tem não. Toda implementação de `BigNumber` ou `BigInteger` que eu conheça utiliza uma biblioteca de terceiros para tal.

Comment: Mas bibliotecas para isto, não pegar uma que faz outra coisa que tem por acaso algo que faça o que deseja, mas não seja o objetivo dela :)

Comment: Alguma em específico ? Recomenda algum material para resolver meu problema ?

Comment: Considerando que o OpenSSL tem uma licença até que conveniente, e tem para praticamente qualquer plataforma, provavelmente poderia continuar usando essa mesma. Agora, se usa OpenSSL só pra isso, como o @Maniero mencionou, uma alternativa dedicada talvez seja mais interessante. Por outro lado, se a aplicação usa OpenSSL, use o que já tem.

Answer (score 2):

As bibliotecas padrões não fornecem suporte para operações aritméticas com valores de mais de 64 bits.

Operações com números inteiros grandes podem ser feitas com a utilização de uma biblioteca da `GNU` chamada [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/).

Segue um exemplo onde os dois argumentos (inteiros grandes) passados para a `main()` são multiplicados e seu resultado exibido na tela:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN    (128)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char res[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];

    mpz_t a, b, c;

    mpz_init(a);
    mpz_init(b);
    mpz_init(c);

    mpz_set_str( a, argv[1], 10 );
    mpz_set_str( b, argv[2], 10 );

    mpz_mul( c, a, b );

    mpz_get_str( res, 10, c );

    printf("%s\n", res );

    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
    mpz_clear(c);

    return 0;
}
```

compilando:

```
$ gcc -lgmp -Wall bigintmul.c -o bigintmul
```

Testando:

```
$ ./bigintmul 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 9876543219876543219876543219876543210
```

Saída:

```
12193263124676116335924401657049230176967230591384377380136092059011263526900
```

Checando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante o autor verificar se a licença da lib recomendada permite o uso onde ele precisa. Provavelmente seria bom mencionar também alguma alternativa com licença MIT ou BSD.